# How to run shell script by including "cd" command in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminal

I am trying to execute a shell script for automating the process rather than manually running the python script. But i am getting the error folder not found.

```
cd /home/gaurav/AndroPyTool

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/android-sdk-linux/

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

source ~/.bashrc

source droidbox_env/bin/activate

alias mycd='cd /home/gaurav/AndroPyTool/test'
mycd
pwd

python androPyTool.py -all -csv EXPORTCSV.csv -s mycd

>>>> AndroPyTool -- STEP 1: Filtering apks

Folder not found!
```

This is the error i am getting because the script is not able to find the path that i have provided above. 
The part after "-s" in the code represents the folder path where the file stored.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are not passing the path to the python program. The python program is not aware of bash aliases and bash will only expand aliases when it is interpreting the token as a command.

When bash reads `python androPyTool.py -all -csv EXPORTCSV.csv -s mycd` It interprets `python` as the command and all other space separated tokens are arguments that will be passed into python. Python then invokes `androPyTool.py` and passes the subsequent arguments to that script. So the program is receiving literally `mycd` as the argument for `-s`.

Moreover, even if `mycd` is expanded, it wouldn't be the correct argument for `-s`. `androPyTool.py` is expecting just the `/path/to/apks`, not `cd /path/to/apks/`.

I don't really think that using the alias in this script makes much sense. It actually makes the script harder to read and understand. If you want to wrap a command, I recommend defining a function, and occasionally you can use variable expansion (but that mixes code and data which can lead to issues). **EDIT: As has been pointed out in the comments, aliases are disabled for scripts.**

Finally there are some other suspicious issues with your script. Mainly, why are you sourcing `.bashrc`? If this script is run by you in your user's environment, `.bashrc` will already be sourced and there is no need to re-source it. On the other hand, if this is not intended to be run in your environment, and there is something in the `.bashrc` file that you need in your script, I recommend pulling just that out and nothing else.

But the most immediate issue that I can see is that sourcing `.bashrc` after you modify path runs the risk of overwriting the changes to `PATH` you just made. Depending on the contents of the `.bashrc` file, sourcing it may not be idempotent, meaning that running it more than once could have side effects. Finally, anything could get thrown in that `.bashrc` file down the road since that's what its for. So now your script may depend on something that likely will be changing. This opens up the possibility that bugs will creep in to your script unexpectedly.

Comment: I agree with everything here, and have a couple of additional worries: first, aliases are really intended for interactive use, and are (by default) disabled in scripts. So don't try to use them there. Second, when using `cd` in a script, you should always include an error check of some sort, because without it if the `cd` fails the rest of the script will go ahead and try to run in the wrong place, wreaking who knows what kind of havoc. Something like this: `cd /path || { echo "Error changing directory." >&2; exit 1; }` (Or you  can use `set -e`, but that has its own problems.)

Comment: Good additions. But I actually think `set -e` is a good way to write a robust script. Occasionally it is tolerable for a command to fail in which case `set -e` can be disabled for just that command or `cmd || true` can be used.